# C# write object to file in human-readable text

Tags: c#, object, serialization, textwriter

Do there exist any standard mechanisms or processes to output any C# object to file in human-readable text format ?

Unlike serialization ( `BinaryFormatter.Serializer` ) this would not ever require reading back the object from file.

Comment: Is JSON not a valid solution?

Comment: Have you looked into JSON?  There is a built in JSONDataContractFormatter and also several nuget libraries that can help you out with that

Comment: xml / json / yaml serialization (ordered by human readability increase)

Comment: Would [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10y9yyta(v=vs.110).aspx) not work?

Comment: `.ToString()` seem to be perfect fit... Are you interested in reading it back too?

Answer (score 3):

There are many different "human readable" formats you could use to represent data (XML, JSON, YAML, etc).  A common one is JSON.

There is a library called [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) that is very heavily used in the .NET community for handling JSON.  You can use built in .NET methods but I prefer this nuget package.  With JSON.NET you can do something as simple as:

```
MyClass someObject = new MyClass();
someObject.SomeProperty = "Foo";
someObject.SomeOtherProperty = "Bar";
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
```

That string "json" would look similar to this:

```
{
    "SomeProperty":"Foo",
    "SomeOtherProperty":"Bar"
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KGPZ61) that shows a sample class I created and how it looks when its serialized into JSON.